# how to know voice button click of a carkit in mirrorlink common api

Tags: mirrorlink

which api is trigerred when the user clicks on the voice control of carkit in mirrorlink mode .

suppose user click on the steering mounted voice control button .How to capture that event in mirrorlink app .

Answer (score 0):

The MirrorLink CommonAPI service calls the IDeviceStatusListener's onMicrophoneStatusChanged method.
If the argument is true the microphone was opened, false if it was closed.

CommonAPI in General: https://causeway.carconnectivity.org/wg/DevWG/document/1989
Java Doc for the Android Version of the CommonAPI: https://causeway.carconnectivity.org/wg/DevWG/document/2119

Example:

```
IDeviceStatusListener devStatusListener = new IDeviceStatusListener.Stub() {
    @Override
    public void onDriveModeChange(boolean isDriving) throws RemoteException {        }

    @Override
    public void onNightModeChanged(boolean isNight) throws RemoteException {  }

    @Override
    public void onMicrophoneStatusChanged(boolean micActive) throws RemoteException {  
        if (micActive) {
            //do s.th. great with the microphone input
        } else {
            //stop your recording or so
        }
    }
};
```

And where you set up your CommonAPI service acccess, do not forget to link the listener to the service:

```
devStatMng = commonapiService.getDeviceStatusManager(packagename, devStatusListener);
```

Comment: I want to differentiate between setMicrophoneOpen() api and voicebutton click as both will result in on microphone status changed callback

Comment: I think this is best done with an internal state machine. If setMicOpen was called and onMicStatusChange(true) came => it is the setMicOpen method. Otherwise it was the external mic open call.